# jEdit text editor - render/preview RTF file

Tags: text-editors, plugins, rtf, jedit

How can I render/preview RTF file using jEdit i.e show the compiled RTF file and not the RTF source code?

I heard that the Info Viewer plugin can achieve this. But when I opened the RTF file in jEdit text editor and then go to `plugins -> Info Viewer -> Open current buffer with browser` then the info viewer window is showing only the RTF source code instead of rendering/compiling the RTF file

Comment: http://plugins.jedit.org/list.php?category=4

Comment: http://community.jedit.org/?q=node/view/37856